# Detect and exclude dynamically changes in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can listen for any input change using this:

```
$('#input-field').on('input', () => {
   // executes even with dynamic changes
});
```

If you change the content of the above element via this:

```
$('#input-field').val('some text')
```

the listener detects the change and fires.

I want to listen for input changes But I don't want to fire it when input has been changed dynamicslly using `val()` ?

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you supply a minimal repo. Heres an example of it working fine https://jsfiddle.net/omy7gbxf/

Comment: input event only triggers with user interaction. Provide a [mre] that demonstrates the behavior you describe